# how to add a column and save in a text file sparse matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

TfidfVectorizer returns sparse matrix on output, which can be easily converted into SparseDataFrame (not the regular one). But I can't figure out how to add a column(s) to it and save in a csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

def get_features(data, train=False):
    tfv = TfidfVectorizer()
    if train:
        features = tfv.fit_transform(data["text"])
    else:
        features = tfv.transform(data["text"])

    features_pd = pd.SparseDataFrame([ pd.SparseSeries(features[i].toarray().ravel())
                                 for i in np.arange(features.shape[0]) ], columns = tfv.get_feature_names() )
# the next 2 lines in replacement of the previous result in empty (commas only) output  
#    features_pd = pd.DataFrame([ pd.Series(features[i].toarray().ravel())
#                                 for i in np.arange(features.shape[0]) ], columns = tfv.get_feature_names() )
# the next line results in TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types ...   
   # features_pd['_class_'] = pd.SparseSeries(data["class"])

    print "F:",features_pd.iloc[[0]]
    return features_pd

if __name__ == '__main__':

    train = pd.read_csv('train.csv', header=None, names = ["class", "text"]).fillna("")
    features = get_features(train, train=True)
    features.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

sparse matrix can be converted to array and thereafter all operations can be performed using regular dataframe
the core of the change to be made: `features.toarray()`

```
features_pd = pd.DataFrame(data=features.toarray(),
                           columns = tfv.get_feature_names() )

features_pd['_class_'] = pd.Series(data["class"], index = features_pd.index)
```